# React Native real time compiling drops huge frame while developing application

Tags: react-native

I'm developing a audiobook application that users can listen books, read them, add them to their fav list and etc. My application size is too heavy, as you guess.
React Native compiles my code while I type, instead pressing `cmd +s`. So that makes huge frame drops in my mac. Despite my spec is enough for coding. Here is my spec:

- MacBook Air
- M2, 2022
- Chip - Apple M2
- Memory - 16 GB
- macOS - Ventura 13.0.1

So, **my question is**: *is there anyway tell react native, compile when i press `cmd + s`*

I read some medium and geeksforgeeks article for this issue. But I couldn't find something worth.

Comment: What editor do you use? Do you have auto save on? are you looking to only save upon pressing the specified keys? is there some sort of delay added there? check your editor settings for all of this.

Comment: Oh. I hate this auto save thing! I always turned it off, no idea why it is on (facepalm) I use Visual studio code.